# Converting "2010-02-15T20:05:28.000Z" in GMT format using Java

Tags: java

I have a string like the following "2010-02-15T20:05:28.000Z" and I need to output the string in GMT format using Java.

BTW, I have no idea what format the date is currently in.

Comment: GMT is not a format, it's a time zone. And Java has several libraries for dealing with date parsing and formatting, just use Google and, if you have a specific question about problems you're having with the code, then try SO.

Comment: I now understand that the string is already in GMT timezone as Jeff Storey pointed out. I ended up parsing the string using DatatypeConverter and used SimpleDateFormat to set the timezone and format the parsed string into the desired format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse date strings of any format using `SimpleDateFormat`, see the reference of its [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) method.

Your format is probably `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`, note that you might want to handle the `Z` (timezone) separately, not sure if `SimpleDateFormat` handles that directly.

Comment: I did not use java.text.SimpleDateFormat to parse the date string. Instead, I used it to create a new java.text.DateFormat object, then set the time zone and format the parsed date string. Either way, your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This format is xml-schema, You can convert like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String dateStr = "2010-02-15T20:05:28.000Z";
try {
    Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(date.toGMTString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This method can be used, I have run.

Comment: I don't like your solution because the toGMTString() method has been deprecated as of JDK 1.1. I prefer to use the DateFormat.format(Date date), using a GMT TimeZone.

Answer (score 2):

The date format is [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The Joda library is really useful here. See their [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html)

Note the `Z` at the end of the time indicates GMT, but it could be non-GMT time zones as well.

Comment: Yes, I now realize that Z corresponds to GMT and Zulu time.

Answer (score 2):

This is format is commonly used in XML to represent date+time, and it is actually ISO8601.
The easiest way to parse it is to use javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter:

```
Calendar dateTime = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2010-02-15T20:05:28.000Z");
```

Comment: You are too strict on wording - it is called date time in the JDK which is ISO8601 according to xml/xsd specs. Anyway you have to admit - it is the easiest way to parse it without importing extra libraries.

Comment: Agreed. If you add that to the post I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Yes, I am able to parse the string in ISO 8601 format using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.